# jQuery Event on Dynamically added element not firing

Tags: jquery

I've been searching for how to do this and I've seen a lot of options (most of which are deprecated), but nothing I've tried has worked.

I have a file upload script that dynamically adds table rows and one `<td>` has some `<button>` elements that I need to do some Ajax work on click, but I can't seem to make it do anything.

Here's the `<td>`that contains the button that gets added to the DOM:

```
<td class="filedelete">
    <button class="btn btn-danger delete">
        <i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i> Delete
    </button>
</td>
```

This is the jQuery I am trying now:

```
$(".delete").on("click", function(event){
    console.log("clicked");
});
```

Is `.on` what I should be using? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Yes you should `.on` but also read the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events)

Comment: I'm not sure, but I don't think the <i> element semantically can have a class.

Comment: i element is not semantic in the first place

Comment: It's a part of Twitter Bootstrap and it's how they apply icons to buttons in the documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your code so that the event handler is bound to a containing element (maybe the parent `<table>` or another containing element that is static) like this:

```
$("#containing_element").on("click", ".delete", function(event){
    console.log("clicked");
});
```

The click event triggered from `.delete` will then bubble up and be caught by the containing element.

Comment: Still no luck, I tried using the table ID as well as the td class and neither works

Comment: @MotiveKyle: Is the table itself being inserted dynamically?

Comment: Ah, my bad, it is added dynamically, just at a different point, I'll try another element